# Visual Studio 2015 Blend - Toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, toolbox

I recently installed Visual Studio 2015 Blend, but can't find the toolbox!
I have searched and searched, but haven't been able to locate it, and it's quite essential, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try: View -> Other Windows -> Toolbox or ctrl + alt + x

Answer (score 0):

Click Toolbox on the View menu. You can dock the Toolbox, and you can pin it open or set it to Auto Hide.

Comment: There is no Toolbox-option in the View-menu on my system.

Answer (score 0):

In the Solution Explorer Pane there should be 4 tabs (my tabs are on the bottom).  Select Assets.  In the Assets pane on the left are groups, click through these to discover all the controls.  Be sure to expand all of the categories as many of the controls are nested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a total newbie to Visual Studio and Blend and I was looking for help to the same question. In my case the tools appeared only when in the Solution Explorer view I right-clicked Assets, chose Add >> New Item >> Visual C++ >> XAML >> Content Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. there is no toolbox for blend and also there are no any components in Assets window.
goto : **View ⇒ Edit in Visual Studio**

This will open Visual Studio another application.
there is toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Design --> Show Tools

You can also type "Tool" into Quick Launch, the first result should be "Design --> Show Tools" which will do that same thing

It is a different tool box from Visual Studio

They are on the left within the Designer window. In the tool box there is an >> icon which opens all controls.

Answer (score 0):

In Blend for VS 2019 and VS 2017 it is called "Assets". It is under **View--> Assets Window**, or **ctrl + alt + x**